# Create Editor with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I ask the question again here because I can't find a solution that works, how do I make it so that when I click an html tag is added example: `<strong></strong>` with text in the middle and if I click again I get out of the html tag?

with the method I use I only add style but when I console.log I don't get what I want, moreover all the content of my textarea becomes bold .

thanks again.

**html**

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>textarea</mat-label>
    <textarea #myTextArea matInput formControlName="editor"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**ts.file**

```
  @ViewChild('myTextArea') public textarea: ElementRef;

  public isBold: boolean = false;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  addBoldStyle() {
    this.isBold = !this.isBold;
    if (this.isBold) {
      this.textarea.nativeElement.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    } else {
      this.textarea.nativeElement.style.fontWeight = null;
    }
  }

  add() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
```

Comment: You have to pick the selected text and wrap that with the strong tag.

Comment: this is the theory how to do in practice please?

Comment: [See these docs if it helps.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)

Comment: One suggestion is to have a textarea as a editor and one div as a preview of the edit. Just toggle them to see the updates then. Or use a div which is editable.

Comment: Maybe some too similar way: 
Write in your code some *ngIf block with <strong> inside and and one elseBlock without <strong>. Depending on your state isBold, the current textarea is displayed. With binding the text to some variable you can make sure, the text you are writing inside stays